# Extending layout from another directory in Laravel 5.4 using module structure

Tags: php, laravel, structure, modular

I'm developing a module and I'm trying to extend `bill.php.blade` in `index.php`
The directory structure looks like this:

```
├── modules
│   ├── Blog
│   │   |
│   │   ├── Resources
│   │   │   ├── lang
│   │   │   └── views->index.blade.php
│   │   │       └── layouts
├── resources
    |
    └── views
        ├── layouts->bill.blade.php
```

So when I try `@extends('resources.views.layouts.bill)` it throws `View [resources.views.layouts.bill] not found`
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's `@extends('layouts.bill');`

Comment: I would swear that I tried this the first time. I feel so dumb, thank you very much @kerbholz

Comment: No problem, glad it works

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it editing your config/view.php file:

```
'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
    ],
```

Add your paths to the array.

```
'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
        base_path('modules/Blog/Resources/views')
    ],
```